# Can apt-get be used on Red Hat systems?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, apt-get

We know that `apt-get` is used on debian based systems so what is used on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) systems? Is it possible to install and use `apt-get` on Red Hat?

Comment: `aptitude` or `apt-get` is the Debian package manager.  In RedHat distributions, the package manager is `rpm` or `yum` for the Fedora/Centos flavours.  You could probably figure out a way to manually install aptitude on RedHat, but that sounds like quite a bit of work.

Comment: No, you should be using yum.

Comment: Even if you could get it installed, would any of the downloaded packages work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a project out there that claims to support `apt` style repositories (as well as the `apt-get` command) on RPM based distros. It is called [apt-rpm](http://apt-rpm.org/) and is used as the default package manager on a few distros, though not on RHEL/Fedora.

Problems:

- It seems not to be really maintained since ~2008; it may have incremental patches or fixes since then, but nothing major.
- Yum repositories are not compatible with `apt-rpm`, so even if you were to install it on your computer, you would need an apt-rpm repository to connect to in order to use it.

There is a fork of `apt-rpm` that has been updated to be mostly compatible with `rpm` version 5, which is used in all recent RPM distros. So if you insist on using it, a good starting point is to check out [the Gitorious branch](https://gitorious.org/rpm5distro/apt-rpm) for apt-rpm for rpm5.

The command syntax of `yum` is close enough to `apt-get` that you should be able to learn one if you know the other within a day, or at most, a week. So unless there is some very strong business need for using `apt` and you're willing to create your own apt-rpm repository (and deal with the cruftiness of software that's basically unmaintained), I would advise against proceeding down this train of thought.

Comment: just small query i simply tried to cut a file from current directory to other directory using this command {sudo rm filename ./Desktop} and it said  that **user is not is the sudoers file. This incident will be reported** . Doesn't this means that SUDO is available in RHEL

Comment: First thing: `rm` removes a file, not moves it. Do NOT use `rm` unless you wish to **delete** a file (possibly with no ability to recover it). Use `mv` instead to rename or move files. Considering that you almost deleted a file by mistake, I would advise you to learn basic console commands **before** you become root, so you don't destroy your system.

Comment: Oh sorry it was **mv** not **rm** apologies. A TYPO

Comment: Anyway, your question is off-topic for the comments of this question, as it is completely unrelated. This is not a chatroom. If you have a question about Sudo on RHEL, ask a new question -- although I'd advise you to **search** SuperUser first because this question has been asked dozens of times.

Answer (score 16):

No, `apt` is Debian specific. `apt` uses `dpkg` to install `.deb` files (which are binary files that are specific to Debian).

Red Hat based Linux distributions uses the `rpm` package management system. You can use `yum` to retrieve and install *rpms* on Red Hat distributions:

```
 yum search som-package-name
 yum install some-package-name
```

If you want to install an *rpm* that you've downloaded on your own, you could use `rpm -i some-package.rpm` to install it (and `rpm -qa` to retrieve a list of all installed *rpms*). This is equivalent to `dpkg -i some-package.deb` (and `dpkg --get-selections` to retrieve a list of all installed *deb* packages) on Debian based distributions.